# Запуск 30 процессов в bat файле

Tags: cmd, bat

Мне надо запустить около 30 раз одну и ту же утилиту для разных файлов. Файл выглядит так:

```
cd..
cd..
cd wwwroot\static\release_dev\css

start /B rtlcss adminHome.css adminHome_rtl.css
start /B rtlcss core.css core_rtl.css
start /B rtlcss engagementRpt.css engagementRpt_rtl.css
start /B rtlcss multiSelectBox.css multiSelectBox_rtl.css
start /B rtlcss serviceKey.css serviceKey_rtl.css
start /B rtlcss sprites.css sprites_rtl.css

start /B rtlcss admin/adminMemberEnroll.css admin/adminMemberEnroll_rtl.css
start /B rtlcss admin/creditCardActivity.css admin/creditCardActivity_rtl.css
start /B rtlcss admin/cust_support.css admin/cust_support_rtl.css
start /B /WAIT rtlcss admin/exportEngagements.css admin/exportEngagements_rtl.css
```

В конце добавляю /WAIT, чтобы окно не закрывалось.
Надо, чтобы запуски происходили последовательно, каждый следующий после окончания предыдущего, чтоб последовательно видеть сообщения об успешности или ошибках. У меня же они фактически запускаются в разнобой.
Какие параметры мне нужно указать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил с помощью команды CALL:

```
call rtlcss adminHome.css adminHome_rtl.css
call rtlcss core.css core_rtl.css
call rtlcss engagementRpt.css engagementRpt_rtl.css
call rtlcss multiSelectBox.css multiSelectBox_rtl.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что тебе `/WAIT` нужно добавить после каждого `START`.

> /W or /WAIT  Start application and wait for it to terminate.
>                   (see below)

В противном случае, у тебя действительно недетерминированный запуск программ. Так как ты, например, запустил 3 программы через свой пакетный файл.

Первые 2 тяжелые и запускаются за 5 сек, а последняя быстрая и запускается за 1 сек. В итоге у тебя запуск выполняется с конца.

Comment: В этом случае выполняется первый запуск и на том заканчивается